# Build a date from a string and date fields and compare against another date. SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to compare dates as part of a where clause in SQL.
One date is called ExitDate and is a standard DateTime field.
The other date is one the needs to be drawn from a varchar(5) field called Renewal which holds "dd/mm" section of a date.

The comparison that I need is to take the 'year' from ExitDate, add the 'dd/mm' string from the Renewal field and then compare that date with Exitdate as a whole.

After that there is a case when that the takes the composite date made as above and then adds 4 or 5 years depending on the outcome of the comparrision.

So far I have code that extracts the year from the EXITDATE field, converts that to a string, adds the "dd/mm" string on from that RENEWAL field and then converts that back to a date for comparision. After the comparison it does it again but also has the DATEADD function to add the years to the date.

```
AND ed.EXITDATE is not null
and s.EDATE > case when 
convert(datetime,(p.RENEWAL + '/' + convert(varchar(4),YEAR(ed.exitdate))),102) > ed.exitdate
then DATEADD(year,-5,convert(datetime,(p.RENEWAL + '/' + convert(varchar(4),YEAR(ed.exitdate))),102))
else DATEADD(year,-4,convert(datetime,(p.RENEWAL + '/' + convert(varchar(4),YEAR(ed.exitdate))),102)) end
```

I currently get the error : The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Is there an easier method of doing this or am I missing something from the converts that would cause this issue?

EDIT:

To assist here is an example of the tables involved
All dates involved are format dd/mm/yyyy

```
Table ED
ID      |EXITDATE(datetime)
1       |01/05/2018
2       |06/10/2018

Table Renewal
Scheme  |RENEWAL(VARCHAR(5))
1       |02/06
2       |04/08

Table s
SalNo   |ID   |EDATE
1       |1    |02/05/2015
2       |1    |02/05/2016
3       |1    |02/05/2017
4       |1    |02/05/2018
1       |2    |18/05/2015
2       |2    |18/05/2016
3       |2    |18/05/2017
4       |2    |18/05/2018
```

I am looking to take the year from EXITDATE Match with against ID=Scheme and add the two strings together; ie. ID1 would produce 02/06/2018 and ID2 would produce 04/08/2018 and compare that against the original EXITDATE.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: share schema and sample data to work on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 103 instead of 102 as per your data.Refer [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_convert.asp).